# Optional parameter in api method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The optional parameter “type” accepts a list of strings in the API.
Although it is never needed to pass more than one type to it, but there can be cases, when it should not be passed at all.

How can I modify this method so that it accept either zero or one parameter?

```
const checkIfExists = async (type: string) => {
   const result = await some_api.list(
       {
         limit: 1,
         type: [type],
       }
   );

   return result.data.length > 0
};
```

Comment: This looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript. Do you also need a working type declaration for the overloaded method?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making parameter optional?

Your function declaration can look like this:
`const checkIfExists = async (type?: string) => {}`  or `const checkIfExists = async (type: string='defaultValue') => {}`

In the first case, the parameter will be optional, so you can send either one or zero argument, and in the second declaration, you use any default type if it is applicable in your case.